# How will diesel engine perform with air in fuel line?

Tags: diesel, ram, fuel-filter

I recently replaced a fuel filter in my 2005 Dodge Ram 3500 Cummings (5.9L). I'm now getting performance issues: at low speed, and especially starting from a stopped position, I'm getting low power. Normally the tachometer jumps right up and the power flows immediately. However at high speeds (like on the highway) I don't notice any power issues and it seems to behave normally.

Does this sound like perhaps I have air in the fuel line?

Side note: my exhaust looks good, no unusual color and is mostly smoke free.

Comment: The motor will stutter and have power loss. I recently had to bleed a diesel motor out because some filled in with gasoline. After I removed the gas I had to repressurize the system.. It stuttered stuttered and once the pressure was right it came alive.

Comment: I don't have any stuttering - just the power loss.

Comment: please disregard my previous answer as it is not applicable to your vehicle.... My apologies

Comment: I checked my diagnostic port using Torque and it had only one code: P0868 "low line pressure <in the transmission>". I reset the code to see if it would come back again. It hasn't! Nor has my low power issue. So, weirdly enough, this problem solved itself. For example this morning it was 33 degrees F outside (cold), I warmed up my truck for 5 minutes, and at the stop light on the corner I gave it some gas: instant power, no issue at all.

Comment: the air probably worked itself out of the system with you running it. Double check transmission fluids. Because just power loss would be explained by that...

Comment: When my diesel truck had air in the fuel it staggered and had rough start with no power.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of marking this question answered:

Sapbucket said "I checked my diagnostic port using Torque and it had only one code: P0868 'low line pressure in the transmission'. I reset the code to see if it would come back again. It hasn't! Nor has my low power issue. So, weirdly enough, this problem solved itself. For example this morning it was 33 degrees F outside (cold), I warmed up my truck for 5 minutes, and at the stop light on the corner I gave it some gas: instant power, no issue at all."

Answer (score 0):

Look for rotten fuel lines first the darker the more suspicious my sump pump to fuel tank return was the worst ever the fuel lines need to be tested with a tight bend.